# controling page order when printing multiple jpgs to pdf windws 10

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing

I have 4 jpg images that I want to combine into a single pdf.

This can be done in windows 10 by selecting the files in the explorer and choosing print using the Microsoft pdf printer [as explained here](https://www.howtogeek.com/248462/how-to-combine-images-into-one-pdf-file-in-windows/)

Does anyone know what controls the order by which it decides to add the images to the pdf?

Answer (score 2):

After playing with this for a while I finally figured it out.
The answer provided by duDE is what I expected originally but did not happen...
It is Almost correct but still...

It turns out the "secret" is that when you right click to get the context menu the mouse must be on the first page to be printed.

It would seem that the order in which the selected files are printed is:
1) The file you right click to get the context menu
2) The rest of the files by the order they are displayed in the explorer window.

If multiple ranges of files are selected it is just the same and is not related in any way to the order in which you do the actual selection of the files.

Comment: Thank you a bunch! I faced the same issue 5 years since you faced it. I have no idea why they implemented such a strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in the link you added:

> Once you have your images **in the right order**, select them all and
>   right-click on them. Select “Print” from the popup menu.

That means, you can easy manipulate the order of the picture by renaming them.
So to say, what you see is what you get:

[image]